# Protecting PK properties on POCO's used by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco

How do you go about protecting the primary key property on a POCO object that is used by EF?

If I have a POCO like so:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

How do I prevent someone form changing the value of the `Id`?

Answer (score 1):

EF uses reflection to set property values. Thus, even private setter will work:

`public Id { get; private set; }`

Answer (score 0):

You could mark the setter as `internal`, that way only the containing assembly classes can modify it.

```
public class Customer
{
   public int Id { get; internal set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   ....
}
```

Comment: Would EF be able to hydrate the field if it is set as internal?

Comment: If the generated classes are in the same assembly yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what purpose you are using EntityFramework for, but keep in mind that if that field is getting serialized either for a web app or a service, users will still be able to modify that field. So when you are saving any object to your database, you should always verify that a user has the authority to edit that object.